# Ajax not working and console not giving any error-MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

**I am working on Create Page.when user Enter the text in textbox it will pass string to action name "CheckRecord" which is PartialViewResult
 then return to the main view "Create".
*Create View:***

```
<input type="text" id="enginNo" />
 <input type="button" value="search" id="btnSearch" />

<div id ="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            var enginNo = $('#enginNo').val();
            $.ajax({
                cashe :'false',
      type: 'Get',
      data: { enginNo: enginNo },
      url: '@Url.Action("CheckRecord")',
      dataType: 'HTML',  // add this line
      success: function (result) {
          $('#result').html(result);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
              alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
              alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
              alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
          } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
              alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
          } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
              alert('Time out error.');
          } else if (exception === 'abort') {
              alert('Ajax request aborted.');
          } else {
              alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
          }
      }
 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Create Action:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
     return View();
    }
```

**CheckResult Action:**

```
   public PartialViewResult CheckRecord(string enginNo)
        {
            if(enginNo == null)
            { 
            var StockDM = db.StockDMs.Where(c => c.EngineNumber == "54-21-31-AF-31");
                return PartialView("_Part", StockDM.ToList());
            }
            else
            { 
                var StockDM = db.StockDMs.Where(c => c.EngineNumber == enginNo);
                return PartialView("_Part", StockDM.ToList());
            }
        }
```

**Partial View "_Part"**

```
@model IEnumerable<SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChasisNumber)

}
```

> **The problem is that data is returning from database is perfectly but not loaded on div from ajax control...and also console is not giving
>   any errors...may be some stupid error...Please help,,,,Thanks for your
>   time**

Comment: add a error callback in your ajax request and see what is the error.

Comment: Where is controller name in `'@Url.Action("CheckRecord")'`

Comment: its not cashe :false , it is Cache:false.

Comment: data: { 'enginNo': enginNo },

Comment: @Manoj.yes you can post it as answer,,,,,

Comment: three modifications and it is now working,,, thanks to all friends,,,someone post it as answer???

Comment: i want to upvote, all comments were usefull,,,and i have not enough reputation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
      cashe :'false',
      type: 'Get',
      data: { enginNo: enginNo },
      url: '@Url.Action("CheckRecord","ControllerName")',
      dataType: 'HTML',  // add this line
      success: function (result) {
          $('#result').html(result);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
           ............
      }
 });
```

Add controller name in `'@Url.Action("CheckRecord")'`